# Frontend and backend connection -node and angular in mvc pattern

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-resource

How to display the following json in scroll bar using angularjs mvc

myjson whixh i get from api localhost:port/details using nodejs:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "notes": "sdas 123",
    "invoice": "232",
    "objectType": "Customer",
    "objectId": 5,
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-29T22:54:06.000Z",
    "dateModified": "2015-10-08T23:01:16.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "notes": "sample Test",
    "invoice": "123",
    "objectType": "Customer",
    "objectId": 5,
    "dateCreated": "2015-09-30T06:38:52.000Z",
    "dateModified": "2015-09-30T01:20:38.000Z"
  }
]
```

Any help guys..?
yes i have started and tried like this :in my controller

my config as:

```
angular.module('customerdetails).config(['$stateProvider',
 function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.
state('listCust', {
    url: '/details',
    templateUrl:  "/customerdetails/views/listcustomer.client.view.html'              
});
}
```

]);

my service:

```
angular.module('customer').factory('Customer',function($resource)
{ 
  return $resource('/details'); 
  });
```

my controller:

```
    angular.module('customerdetails').controller('CustomerController',            ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location',           'Authentication', 'Customer', 'InvoiceRefund', '$filter',
     function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $http,  $stateParams, $location,    Authentication, Customer, $filter) {

     var cus = Customer.query(function() {
       console.log(cus);


      });
```

Comment: can you provide the code of your html page and angularjs ?

Answer (score 0):

To display JSON data you can use follwoing syntax: `{{variable | json}}` in the template, but for that you need to assign `$scope.variable = YOUR_JSON;` in your controller code

Comment: Thanks Shershen,but here i need to get json data from api "/details' which i have been created using nodejs .As iam new to angular,i need to know how to get that api using $resource in service  and define in controller for angular.

Comment: then you should start from one of the tutorials like that one for example - http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/, this is how to write super-simple controller - http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Comment: yes i have started and tried like this :in my controller angular.module('customerdetails').controller('CustomerController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Customer', 'InvoiceRefund', '$filter',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $http,  $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Customer, $filter) {
 
  var customers = Customer.query(function() {
    console.log(customers);
    });
    }
    ]);

Comment: and my service as:   angular.module('customer').factory('Customer',function($resource) {
  return $resource('/details');
  });

Comment: no, posting unreadable chunks of code here won't work. please update your question completely - with data you receive, contoller code and service code etc, then everyone can take a look